# Docker dynamic base image name

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am working on a joint development with another company and we have separate docker regsitry, DNS etc. If I build a docker image and use it as base image in other projects like

```
FROM abc-regsitry.com/custom_centos:1.0
```

the other party, who will use the same source to build the image could not resolve the DNS name abc-registry.com. How can I make the docker registry prefix in the FROM directive dynamic ? Are Dockerfile templates our only option ?

Answer (score 3):

You can set up an additional shared repository.

To copy an image to the shared repo

```
docker pull my-repo.com/myImage
docker tag my-repo.com/myImage shared-repo.com/ourImage
docker push shared-repo.com/ourImage
```

And they can do

```
FROM shared-repo.com/ourImage
```

This way they have a fixed prefix, and the image name is whatever you choose.